# Weird unhandled PDO exception

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo

Does anybody have any idea of what this exception might be about?

> You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances' in [no active
>   file]:0 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]

Thanks

Comment: Any chance we can see the code where this error is thrown?

Comment: Are you using Zend/Symfony by any chance?

Comment: @Prisoner: it's actually a VERY long code, and clearly the error message doesn't give any information about the specific place. I don't think it would help :S

Comment: @Oldskool: no, I'm not using any frameworks

Comment: no active file often means you do something in a deconstructor your are not allowed to.

Comment: @Rufinus could be something not allowed in a _constructor_ too? Maybe something like passing the PDO database object as a reference parameter?

Comment: normaly this shouldn be a problem. do you try to store the PDO object in the session ? no active file also comes when there is an error writing the session.

Comment: Are you trying to serialize an object that happens to contain a reference to a PDO object?  If so then you'll need to implement a __sleep() method to prevent the internal PDO object from being serialized.  You'll then have to give the object a new PDO object after unserialization (or have a __wakeup() method create one, though that approach isn't recommended).

Comment: Wow.. that's pretty messy and it definitely doesn't sound like a good way to go about it. I'll try another approach where I don't store the object with a PDO reference and see if that resolves the error. thanks for the answers guys

Comment: I came across the same issue (luckily i was testing a lot during the build so i noticed it easily) but it was simply an issue with saving a PDO statement as a global variable of the object instead of just the result in my case all i needed was to grab the result and then set it afterward e.g $stmnt = [queryhere]; $this->glob = $stmnt['foo']; hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 3):

From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

> The value to be serialized. serialize() handles all types, except the
>   resource-type

And to clarify the resource part:

> Resources
>
> A resource is a special variable, holding a reference to an external
>   resource.

In your class the resource is the PDO object which holds the connection to the external object (the database).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot store resource type variables in a session.